# C++ program consume CPU when started in script file (Linux shell script)

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have three programs (dmon, dlog, emon). If I start them by running one by one in the terminal as background process (./dmon & ./dlog & ./emon &), these programs work normally.

But when I put these programs into a script file (runapps.sh), they consume CPU a lot (see the picture here)
[CPU consumption when running runapps.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlUic.png)

I need to start these programs automatically at boot-time (in an embedded board). Currently, I put them in the rc.local file and it consumes CPU as above. How to run these programs with less CPU consumption ?

[Update the question]

More detail about these processes:
Each process has several threads (pthread). These threads usually sleep or wait on Unix socket:

```
static void sample_thread_func_0() {
    do_something();
    sleep(1);
}

static void sample_thread_func_1(){
    if (accept_unix_socket()) do_something();
}
```

do_something function just does some regular tasks like checking the storage device (ioctl to eMMC device) or polling input mqtt messages. I'm sure that do_something function does not eat much CPU as top command shows.

I'm wondering about the affect of putting commands into the shell script file. Why the CPU consumption is low if I start these programs one by one in the terminal ?

Comment: Attach a debugger or profiler or run `perf top` and see what the programs are doing with all that CPU time.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're doing in the program, use debugger